# SSIS - Database Table to Excel Destination

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I have a table on a database on sql server with a column:
`[ABCD] [varchar] of 6000

That i want to export to an Excel Destination using SSIS.

> Error: Cannot convert between unicode and non unicode data types. Si
>   tried to use Data Conversion but still i get the same error.

When i look at the data conversion editor i see this.

> InputColumn OutputColumn     DataType              Length  Precision
>   Scale   Code Page
>
> ABCD          Copy of ABCD    string [DT_STR]      6000
>   1252  (ANSI - Latin I)

First it says the length is not valid and must be between 0 and 4000.
I changed that to 4000, now it says that Copy of ABCD has the length,precision,scale or the Code page that is a value other than 0 but the data type requires the value to be 0.

The precision and scale are empty and I cannot change the code page to 0 as it has a dropdown only with other code pages to select from.

How do I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across the issue with Unicode and non-Unicode before and what solved it for me was to change the data type to Unicode String [DT_WSTR] rather than string [DT_STR]. The maximum length for unicode data (i.e. NCHAR or NVARCHAR (when specifying the length)) in a table is 4000 which is why the length of 6000 gives an error. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i tried to change the datatype to DT_WSTR but it dint really help, it still says the same error: Copy of ABCD has the length,precision,scale or the Code page that is a value other than 0 but the data type requires the value to be 0. The precision and scale are empty and I cannot change the code page to 0 as it has a dropdown only with other code pages to select from.